# I want to send the results in a string array

Tags: android, arrays

I want to send the results in a string array instead of text.Here is the code for sending the results in text.But i want to send the results in a string array.

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

try {
    Vector ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/abc/Desktop");

    for(int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
        text += sftpChannel.pwd() + "/" + (((LsEntry)ls.get(i)).getFilename()) + "\n";
    }

    t.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { t.setText(text); }
    });

    } catch (SftpException e1) { }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to send?, currently you are setting the text of an element t (i'm guessing a textview) this method will not accept an array. You could save the value of what is in text as an array though rathern than a concatenated string. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

try {
    Vector ls=sftpChannel.ls("/home/abc/Desktop");
    String[] strings = new String[ls.size];

    for(int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
        strings[i] = sftpChannel.pwd() + "/" + (((LsEntry)ls.get(i)).getFilename());
    }

    t.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { t.setText(strings.toString()); }
    });

    } catch (SftpException e1) { }
```